# How to create ctags only for c and h files in code

Tags: c, tags, ctags

I have a compiled code. If i try generation the tags using the 'usr/bin/ctags -R *', it will include all the c,h,object files etc. So it is taking lot of time and also memory. Could you please let me know how to generate tags only for c/h files.

Answer (score 20):

Use the --languages parameter:

ctags --languages=C

Comment: --languages only can read .c file, but not .h file, it should use: ctags -h=".c.h"

Comment: --languages only includes .c, so you need to also include c++  "--languages=C,C++" which will add .h files as well as several c++ file extensions.  ".h" files have to be processed as C++ since it is a superset and you can't assume they only use C language features

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `.ctagsignore` file to exclude any unwanted files from the generated tags.
The following is an example I use for my projects:

Contents of .ctagsignore:

```
bin
makefile
obj
tags
workspace.vim
```

And then generate tags with:
`-ctags -R --exclude=@.ctagsignore`

This ignores every file in the bin, and obj folder, the makefile, the (future) generated tags file, and the workspace.vim file in the project directory. It essentially works like a .gitignore file, so you can use the wildcard (*.o) notation - myfolder/*.o ignores all object files in $PROJ_DIR$/myfolder/

Answer (score 0):

i would try 'man ctags' and read thru the options.

or you can use shell magic like:

```
ctags `find . -name "*.[ch]" -print`
```

or something like that

Comment: I feel this is the best option.